# Function of Numpy Array with if-statement

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) and [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) to produce some plots. I wish to define a function which given an array returns another array with values calculated *elementwise*, for example:

```
def func(x):
     return x*10

x = numpy.arrange(-1,1,0.01)
y = func(x)
```

This is fine. Now however I wish to have an if-statement inside `func`, for example:

```
def func(x):
     if x<0:
          return 0
     else:
          return x*10

x = numpy.arrange(-1,1,0.01)
y = func(x)
```

This unfortunately throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scripts\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    y = func(x)
  File "D:\Scripts\test.py", line 11, in func
    if x<0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I looked at the documentation for [`all()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130506212046/http://www.scipy.org:80/Numpy_Example_List/#head-147db17da53bc378c2f3f90d4f65f97f1bc6194c) and [`any()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130506212046/http://www.scipy.org:80/Numpy_Example_List/#head-779ee45438f37a2b9e3f957eefc238835f7227c6) and they do not fit the bill for what I need. So is there a nice way to make the function handle arrays element wise as in the first example?

Comment: You have to decide whether you want to treat `x` as `int` or as a `numpy.array`. Or use `ininstance()` to check what type is being passed

Comment: What do you mean by `x<0`? `x` is an array, so it is not clear what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Bjoern Pollex I know that is why python is getting confused, I want to apply this function to each element of the array individually (i.e. elementwise)

Comment: @pajton Indeed but is there a way to make the second handle this gracefully like the first example?

Comment: So what exactly do you want the output to be, for the illustrated input?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to wrap func before applying it to array `x`:

```
from numpy import vectorize
vfunc = vectorize(func)
y = vfunc(x)
```

Comment: Neat. I do believe however, that my solution is faster as long as you use operations for which Numpy has it's own implementations (have not tested it though, just a feeling).

Comment: Sure.  All the built-in ops, such as those you compose, will be faster than pure python. I was just targeting the "is there a nice way to make the function handle arrays element wise?" question.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to make this efficient when using functions written in C (e.g. by using Cython). I have a feeling there might be.

Comment: Accepted this answer since I was after readable code more than speed (this is only a little script after all) :)

Answer (score 22):

I know it is too late for this answer, but I am excited learning NumPy. You can vectorize the function on your own with numpy.where.

```
def func(x):
    import numpy as np
    x = np.where(x<0, 0., x*10)
    return x
```

**Examples**

Using a scalar as data input:

```
x = 10
y = func(10)
y = array(100.0)
```

using an array as data input:

```
x = np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
y = func(x)
y = array([ -1.00000000e+00,  -9.00000000e-01,  -8.00000000e-01,
    -7.00000000e-01,  -6.00000000e-01,  -5.00000000e-01,
    -4.00000000e-01,  -3.00000000e-01,  -2.00000000e-01,
    -1.00000000e-01,  -2.22044605e-16,   1.00000000e-01,
     2.00000000e-01,   3.00000000e-01,   4.00000000e-01,
     5.00000000e-01,   6.00000000e-01,   7.00000000e-01,
     8.00000000e-01,   9.00000000e-01])
```

**Caveats**:

1) If `x` is a masked array, you need to use `np.ma.where` instead, since this works for masked arrays.

Comment: Your solution is similar to mine (`np.where` and `np.choose` behave similiarly in this case), but better!

Answer (score 10):

This should do what you want:

```
def func(x):
    small_indices = x < 10
    x[small_indices] = 0
    x[invert(small_indices)] *= 10
    return x
```

[`invert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html) is a Numpy-function. Note that this modifies the argument. To prevent this, you'd have to modify and return a [`copy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) of `x`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I'm curious as to why `x[x<0]=0 etc` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @Dan: It does work, but the way I show it, the potentially expensive operation `x<0` has to be executed only once (on second thought, `invert` is probably just as expensive, you'd have to test that).

Comment: Well, "x[x<0]=0" works for me. (Python 2.6.1 numpy 2.0.0.dev-3071eab)

Comment: I think using np.where is even better.

Answer (score 9):

*(I realize this is an old question, but ...)*

There is one more option which wasn't mentioned here -- using [`np.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html).

```
np.choose(
    # the boolean condition
    x < 0,
    [
        # index 0: value if condition is False
        10 * x,
        # index 1: value if condition is True
        0
    ]
)
```

Though not terribly readable, this is just a single expression (not a series of statements), and does not compromize numpy's inherent speed (as `np.vectorize` does).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = numpy.arrange(-1,1,0.01)
mask = x>=0
y = numpy.zeros(len(x))
y[mask] = x[mask]*10
```

`mask` is a boolean array that equates to `True` are array indices matching the condition and `False` elsewhere. The last line replaces all values in the original array with that value mulitplied by 10.

Edited to reflect Bjorn's pertinent comment

Comment: It would be even nicer (and correct) if you'd make `y = zeroes(len(x))` and then `y[mask] = x[mask] * 10`.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you need a function

```py
x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)
y = x * np.where(x < 0, 0, 10)
```